# Is there a way to customize the context menu in a Timeline?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, task-list, links

I want to set up a Task List so that a user is able to click on a task and see a link to a page.  The link would be stored in column of the Task List.
[image: example]
An acceptable alternative would be to click on the task and have it go straight to the link.

Is there any way to do this with SharePoint Designer or custom code?